# Installing Checkstyle-Plugin (7.2.0) for Eclipse Neon fails

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I tried to install the checkstyle-Plugin for my eclipse bundle `Eclipse for Java Developers`, by dragging the provided link from http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/#!/ onto my Eclipse window.

Unfortunately this results in the following error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,net.sf.eclipsecs.branding,7.2.0.201611072237
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,net.sf.eclipsecs.checkstyle,7.2.0.201611072237
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,net.sf.eclipsecs.core,7.2.0.201611082201
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,net.sf.eclipsecs.doc,7.2.0.201611082205
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,net.sf.eclipsecs,7.2.0.201611082205
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,net.sf.eclipsecs.ui,7.2.0.201611072237
```

Any idea how I might fix this?

Installing it using the Marketplace also did not work. It failed with:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-cs/files/updatesite/7.2.0/plugins/net.sf.eclipsecs.doc_7.2.0.201611082205.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-cs/files/updatesite/7.2.0/features/net.sf.eclipsecs_7.2.0.201611082205.jar.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Did Marketplace fail with the same message?

Comment: @nitind: I added the error Message to my question

Comment: install certificate into jre cacerts. detailed guide is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40417523/1802348).

Comment: @jaydeep: took me about 45 minutes, but it worked. Can you write an answer from your comment, so that in can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YOU NEED TO INSTALL YOUR NETWORK ROOT SSL CERTIFICATE INTO JRE CACERTS. FOR ANY JAVA PKIX SSL EXAPTION YOU MAY FOLLOW THIS GUIDE.**

**How to get Root Certificate?**

1. Open Google Chrome and navigate to https://sourceforge.net/
2. Click on icon just besides your url. see following image.

[image]

3. Click on View Certificate.You can see hierarchy and select top most certificate in hierarchy
4. Confirm that certificate have ROOT word in its name.
5. Now just bellow that hierarchy part you can see a rectangle image of the certificate. Just drag that image and drop it to your desktop.

**NOW YOU HAVE YOUR ROOT CERTIFICATE!**

**HOW TO INSTALL THIS CERTIFICATE INTO JRE CACERTS?**

Before you proceed further do confirm you had located exactly that jre which is giving this error. Many times IDE uses jre which is bundled with it not system jre. In my case I pointed all my IDE to my system Java installation.

1. use keytool.exe inside your jre bin folder.
2. fire following command to place your certificate inside cacerts file

> keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias ALIASNAME -file
>   /PATH/TO/YOUR/DESKTOP/CertificateName.cer -keystore
>   /PATH/TO/YOUR/JDK/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit

**NOW YOUR PROBLEM IS RESOLVED! RESTART YOUR IDE AND CHECK RESULTS.**

Comment: This procedure roughly solved the problem but I had to import the intermediate and the source forge certificate as well as the root certificate