# Installing pyDev and other plugins for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, exception, eclipse-plugin

I still can't install any plugin for eclipse because of a ValidatorException

[image]

```
Unable to read repository at http://www.pydev.org/updates/content.xml.

sun.security.validator.ValidationException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
find valid certification path to requested target
```

What should I do in that case?

Comment: You need to show us more details.

Comment: Dear greg, what kind of details should i share with you?
if you point out what you want to see, i will share the necessary information

Comment: install your network root certificate to java cacerts. read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40757655/1802348) guide.. it will solve all problems..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a common certificate issue, which can happen because of multiple reasons. I'll list the 2 most likely to be the case here:

1. The URL mentioned in the error does a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, which java does not seem to like.

   I'm not sure if this is still an issue in recent Java versions, could not find a better reference but they mention it here: https://github.com/protegeproject/protege/issues/17

   Please try to change the update-site URL from http://www.pydev.org/updates/ to what it redirects to (which currently is: https://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/5.3.1/)
2. The certificate could not be validated because the certificate issuers root certificate is not in your keystore. Make sure you have the most recent version of java installed (each new version contains a new keystore). You can also add the issuers root certificate (or the certificate of the site) into your keystore using the [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolfilex/rstep1.html).