# Oauth2 server on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am working on a spring boot app using spring security to set up an oauth2 server for use with Amazon Alexa using the authorization code grant flow. As it's a POC, it's using an in memory client and some in memory users. I've set up a working example locally and tested this with Postman.

I've thrown the packaged jar into elastic beanstalk and have it hosted over https using a self signed certificate. When testing with both Alexa and Postman, I'm brought to the login screen and the allow/deny screens, followed by a failure. For alexa, I'm simply shown that account linking failed. For postman, the generated token just contains the message "Could+not+make+access+token+request".

I've checked the network calls that occur for the alexa app and I can confirm that my authorization endpoint redirects with a code and the state that was passed by alexa, but never reaches the token endpoint. However, manually passing this code to the token endpoint provides me a valid token.

This is the first time I'm using every one of these technologies (other than spring boot) so any help would be vastly appreciated here.

**Edit**

So I went ahead and served the endpoints over regular http and I still encountered the same problem using Postman. So I'm pretty confident the issue has anything to do with ssl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I ended up building a dummy client application to go test my Auth server.
I used [this guide](http://www.baeldung.com/sso-spring-security-oauth2) to create this client application using the spring security 
framework.

I ended up getting a `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException` exception, which was caused by the JVM not trusting my self signed certificate. I added my site's certificate using this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40417523/8641777). From there, my local client application was working.

In terms of my end goal, I would need to obtain a trusted certificate for my auth server. I found this out [here](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/articles/38610/alexa-debugging-account-linking.html).

> 6. Note that the account linking URL must be a HTTPS URL on port 443, with a certificate from an Amazon approved CA authority (https://mozillacaprogram.secure.force.com/CA/IncludedCACertificateReport).

The provided link on approved CA's seems to have been moved unfortunately.